# ANDROID ACTIVITY-MAIN.XML NOT APPEARING

Tags: android

Hello i am a beginner to  android.I have been working on eclipse but recently i just downloaded android studio.every thing is coming but in the activity_main.xml layout doesn't appear at all but the paleete appears,rest everything is ok.
can anyone please help  to figure out what to do with this problem?
please.

Comment: is there any option with name preview in it???

Answer (score 5):

Please try to rebuild the project and check this path (Path: yourApp-->src-->main-->res-->layout.) in your layout folder whether your activity xml is present. If you are unable to find, create a layout xml with the name you have used in setcontentview method in your activity onCreate() method.

Kindly first go through [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) to get some initial start and learn according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If your error in rendering layout then, set Android version when use rendering layout in IDE. which is in top right side in layout with android symbol. set lower for your application.!

Answer (score 0):

Share the code of your activity and Are you getting error in "R.layout. activity_main" while using setconetentview.If error is there,check support libraries are updated or not.